# FBX export adding extra bone

Tags: armature, export, .fbx

I'm doing a fbx ascii export on Blender 2.78 to 3ds max 8. This is for Neverwinter Nights 2 models. I notice fbx has added an additional bone, I think it comes from the armature container in Blender, this causes problems with the animation. Is there a way to only export actual bones? On a max nwn2 mdb import the body mesh and bone goes to the scene root in 3ds max(using nwn2utilsmaxplugins).

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: https://krisredbeard.wordpress.com/tutorials/tutorial-prevent-blender-fbx-exporter-adding-extra-root-bone/ YMMV but blender adds another root (an empty) to FBXs, and this "may" fix it for you. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by the "Add Leaf Bones" option. It is checked by default. You can find it in the export options under "Armatures".

[image: Fbx export options]

Comment: No it is not. Leaf Bones are the bones added to the end of the bone hierarchy, the leaves, that is the exact opposite of the root node of the tree.